# Pine script, problems with counting bars in pine script

Tags: boolean, pine-script

I want to display the number of bars between three moving average crossovers, but I don't know how to do it, please help.
[image]

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script")
EMA8_= ta.ema(close,8)
EMA113_= ta.ema(close,113)

bool isCond1 = ta.crossover(EMA8_, EMA113_) 

plot(ta.ema(close,8),color=color.white)
plot(ta.ema(close,113),color=color.aqua)

plotshape(series = isCond1 , style=shape.flag, location=location.top, color=#9FE2BF, size=size.normal)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time your condition is true, you should calculate the Number of bars from the last time. So you must also record the Num of the bar each time the condition is true.
here is a working example :

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script")
EMA8_= ta.ema(close,8)
EMA113_= ta.ema(close,113)

bool isCond1 = ta.crossover(EMA8_, EMA113_) 
var NoBars = bar_index
var NbBars = 0
if isCond1
    NbBars := bar_index - NoBars
    NoBars := bar_index

plot(ta.ema(close,8),color=color.white)
plot(ta.ema(close,113),color=color.aqua)

plotshape(series = isCond1 , style=shape.flag, location=location.top, color=#9FE2BF, size=size.normal)
if isCond1
    label.new(bar_index, close, text=str.tostring(NbBars))
```